# How can pass a multi level single select parameter to a jenkins job using CURL?

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to trigger a Jenkins job with parameters from a remote location using CURL, But the job I want to trigger has a Multi-Level Single Select Parameter defined, so when I try to pass the values to this parameter using CURL, the job is taking an empty value for that parameter.

How can I achieve this successfully?

My curl command is as below,

```
curl -X POST  {{URL_JENKINS/path_to_job}}buildWithParameters \
    --user u_name:password \
    --data PARAM1=aa \
    --insecure
```

Here PARAM1 is defined as multi-level single select in the job I want to trigger, something like below

[This is the parameter defined in job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sruou.png)

Comment: There is also this token that needs to be passed. BTW.. all you need is to remote trigger your jenkins job with build parameters right?

Comment: Thanks, Vijay for the comment.
Yeah, we can use either of those token or user/passwords. We can use the remote trigger plugin as well but there is a limitation that we can't pass Multi-Level Single Select parameters. Looks like this Post request also have the same limitation.

Comment: Can u try `curl -ksu uname:pwd -X POST {jobURL}/buildWithParameters -F PARAM1=aa` ?